# Check SYS_REFCURSOR is null or not

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am working with stored procedure for the first time and I have a stored proc which does some checking to set a SYS_REFCURSOR as NULL.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "proc"
(
    tableRec OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
.
.
BEGIN
.
.
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        tableRec := NULL;
    END;
```

Once this is run, I need to check if tableRec was null or not before running another if loop.
I tried as below

```
BEGIN
    if tableRec = NULL then
```

but this doesnt work. Elsewhere this is possible to check if a number say itemCount, is 0 by writing

```
if itemCount = 0 then
```

Can anyone explain how to achieve this for SYS_REFCURSOR and why it works for number and not for it.
It is not about checking if the SYS_REFCURSOR is empty(because I found information about it on internet) or not but make use of the fact that is it set as NULL

Comment: I would suggest not to use such kind of null check with ref cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `IS NULL` to check if something is null ?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE proc (tableRec OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
as
BEGIN

if tableRec is NULL then
    null;
end if;

END;
/
```

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=acb1c275f786fda1fa26a6a621128bef)